# Is "10% finished" or "finished 10%"?

Tags: usage

I have worked on a task for 3 days and finished about 10% of the task.

How to report to my boss about this status?

1. The task was finished 10%
2. The task has finished 10%
3. The task was 10% finished
4. The task has 10% finished

Which is right? Or is there another way to express my meaning?
I am a new English learner, so could you please be more patient?

Comment: "I'm currently working on the remaining 90%" "I'm about 1/10 of the way"

Comment: You can also put **I** as the subject: "I am 10% finished [with the task]," or "I have have finished 10% [of the task]."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can treat **10%** like **partly**.

> The task was partly finished.
>
> The task is partly finished.
>
> The task has partly completed.

Few speakers would say "The task was finished partly" or "The task has completed partly".

With **only**, the phrase **only partly** can come after or before the past participle:

> The task has completed only partly.
>
> The task has only partly completed.

When you use **is** instead of the auxiliary **has**, **completed** functions  like an adjective, and then you'd want to put **only partly** in front of the adjective:

> The task is only partly completed.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I know 3 points here: 
1. 10% = partly.
2. the usage of only.
3. completed is an adjective in "is completed" but an past-participle in "has completed".

And I want to ask one more question: 
    The task was partly finished.
    The task is partly finished.
    The task has partly completed.
Why not "The task has partly finished"? What is the difference between these two sentenses?

Comment: You can say "partly finished" or "partly completed".